# Pasar un array en vez de una variable al método add de un ArrayList

Tags: java, array, arraylist, parámetros

Luego de inicializar un `ArrayList` de un array de `int`...

```
ArrayList<int[]> lista = new ArrayList<>();
```

Trato de agregar un elemento... Es decir, un array de enteros.

```
lista.add({2,3,4})
```

Pero me da error:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - Syntax error, type annotations are illegal here
> - Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration
> - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
> - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete QualifiedName

Para solucionarlo, lo que hago es declarar la variable en una línea nueva:

```
ArrayList<int[]> lista = new ArrayList<>();
int[] array = {2,3,4};
lista.add(array);
```

Pero no me gusta hacerlo así... Mi pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna manera de declarar el array dentro de los paréntesis de `add` en vez de pasarle una variable ya creada?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para crear un array que se usará en una sentencia, debes usar `new int[] { ... }`:

```
List<int[]> lista = new ArrayList<>();
lista.add(new int[] {2,3,4});
```

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, para la inicialización de un contenedor no se puede utilizar un tipo primitivo (es decir **int**, se puede utilizar **int[]** pero como se desea sólo una matriz de enteros, no veo ningún uso en eso). En su lugar, debe utilizar **Integer**, como sigue:

```
ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Para agregar elementos, simplemente use la **addfunción**:

```
lista.add(1);  
lista.add(22);
lista.add(-2);
```

Sólo para tener en cuenta: **ArrayList** no significa "Lista de matrices", sino más bien una lista que utiliza una matriz internamente.

Tambien puedes hacer lo sigiente:

```
int a1[] = {1,2,3};
ArrayList<Integer> lista =new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i : a1) {
    lista.add(i);        
    System.out.println("Arraylist contains:" + lista.get(0));
}
```

Y si no se lo quieres pasar de una variable ya creada lo haces en el constructor:

```
List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
```

Comment: Me da error: `Arrays cannot be resolved`

Comment: Que versión de java estas usando 7 o 8

Comment: Si importaste el Arrys import java.util.Arrays;

Comment: Cuidado. @ArtEze tiene un `List<int[]>`, no un `List<Integer>`.

Comment: Tienes razon en ello, lo puse en Integer pensando en los argumentos de tipo genérico deben ser objetos. Dado que los primitivos no se extienden Object, no pueden utilizarse como argumentos de tipo genérico para un tipo parametrizado y que integer es el contenedor para int autoboxing, Pero me gusta tu respuesta Luiggi Saludos!!

Comment: @SoftMolina Si importo `Arrays`, y además `List`, de `java.util` funciona correctamente... En realidad no es un `List`, recién me entero que existe esa clase. Yo me refería al `ArrayList`. Siempre trato de pensar que una matriz tiene más de una dimensión. En caso de una sola dimensión le digo vector o array. En mi caso es una lista de arrays, pero generalmente un `ArrayList` es una lista de elementos.