# ¿Cuál es el equivalente de array.push(element); pero en java?

Tags: javascript, java

Estoy trabajando en un port de javascript a Java, pero, necesito meter elemetos a un array y la unica forma que sé hacerlo es con **push()** (en javascript), creí que seria de la misma manera, pero no doy.
Creo que mi pregunta es algo básica, pero voy empezando en eso.
Gracias de desde antes.

Comment: Quizás te sirva mirar [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109081/pasar-un-array-en-vez-de-una-variable-al-m%c3%a9todo-add-de-un-arraylist) que hice hace bastante tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este seria su equivalente en java.

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();

ar.add("HOLA");
ar.add("LUIS");
ar.add("ADIOS");
```

Comment: Oh, estaba fácil. Muchas gracias!!